# Using R to organize/rearrange CSV - group by multiple columns?

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a CSV that I need to clean up / organize in a usable way using R. I need to group by the property ID and then want to take all the unique years for the defor year column and make each year into a sperate column with the amount of deforestation for that year. My data frame / CSV looks like this:

```
Prop_ID deforYear   deforHA
1           2010         15
1           2011         0
1           2012         10
2           2010         35
2           2011         45
2           2012         0
```

and I want the output to look like this:

```
Prop_ID defor_2010  defor_2011 defor_2012
1               15           0         10
2               35          45          0
```

I'm assuming I use the group_by function in dplyr but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very simple using the `pivot_wider` function from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Prop_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  deforYear = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012),
  deforHA = c(15, 0, 10, 35, 45, 0)
)

df %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from=deforYear, values_from=deforHA, names_prefix="deforYear_")

# result
  Prop_ID deforYear_2010 deforYear_2011 deforYear_2012
1       1             15              0             10
2       2             35             45              0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!